# Regex for django api

Tags: python, regex, django-urls

I want to use following urls in my api, using a single `regex`

The urls I needed are

```
testapi/type1/   

testapi/type2/  

testapi/type2/subtype1/   

testapi/type2/subtype2/
```

The regex now I use:

```
(r'^testapi/(?P<type>type1|type2|type3)/(?P<subtype>.*)/$', my_handler),
```

Now the issue is not page not fond for urls like `myapi/type1/` [urls doesn't have subtype]

What is the best solution

Comment: Did you try to make the subtype optional in your regex with `?` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
(r'^testapi/(?P<type>type1|type2|type3)/(?P<subtype>subtype\d+|)/?$', my_handler)

>>  testapi/type2/
>>  [('type2', '')]
>>  testapi/type2/subtype1/
>>  [('type2', 'subtype1')]
>>  testapi/type2/subtype1
>>  [('type2', 'subtype1')]
```

`(?P<subtype>subtype\d+|)` will either capture `subtype<number>` or `<empty string>` .

If you want to make your regex more flexible, you can substitute following:

- `(?P<subtype>subtype\d+|)` --> `(?P<subtype>\w+|)`
- `(?P<type>type1|type2|type3)` --> `(?P<type>\w+)`

These replacement will not require your url to include *subtype* and *type* and accept any string.

Answer (score 0):

Just create two patterns:

```
r('^testapi/type(?P<type\d+)/subtype(?P<subtype>\d+)/$', my_handler),
r('^testapi/type(?P<type>\d+)/$', my_handler),
```

Answer (score 0):

The trailing / on your reg is not optional:

```
(r'^testapi/(?P<type>type1|type2|type3)/(?P<subtype>.*)/$', my_handler),
                                                       ^ here
```

Try adding a ? to make this optional too.